# htmlunit .net MVC Views unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, tdd, htmlunit

I am using htmlUnit from Java (Converted to run in .net) [Details here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/)

I am using the same logic as the example, using the web client and this works perfectly with my MVC3 Razor code/views.
The problem occurs when I have `[Authorize]` above my views as they webclient can't access the page. Is there a way around this? How would I (if possible) set it to automatically log on? If I just parse a login page and do a submit with Admin/Password.. will this carry over to every page visited in this "session"

I have tried:

```
 [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {

            //Initiate WebClient
            webClient = new WebClient();

            //Login
            var loginPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage(properties.DomainNameToTest + "Account/Logon/");
            ((HtmlInput)loginPage.getElementByName("UserName")).setValueAttribute(properties.adminUsername);
            ((HtmlInput)loginPage.getElementByName("Password")).setValueAttribute(properties.adminPassword);
            var action = (HtmlPage)loginPage.getElementByName("loginButton").click();

        }
```

This works fine.

Comment: Is it failing on every attempt?  What is the specific error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlUnit is a web browser. It just doesn't have a graphical user interface: you have to tell it what to do using code. If you're able to access your page using a regular web browser, then just do the same thing with HtmlUnit, and it will work as expected.

Comment: Edited my original post to reflect my attempt at doing this.

Comment: You have to use the same WebClient instance to browse the other pages, after the login. Using a new WebClient is similar to starting a new Browser process (i.e. use Firefox to browse the pages after having authenticated using IE)